# How to run a exe file dependant on another exe file running

Tags: c#

```
static Process[] processArray = new Process[1];
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    bool programIsRunning = false;
    string process = "file location file name .exe";
    processArray = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process));
    Console.WriteLine(processArray);
    do
    {
        if (processArray == null && programIsRunning == false) 
        {
            Process.Start("file location file name .exe"); 
            programIsRunning = true;
        } 
    } while (true);
}
```

When i run this code and launch 1st exe the second one doesn't begin running (its supposed to). however if i do `if (processArray != null && programIsRunning == false)` the 2nd exe file runs even when the first isn't running.

Comment: its much better to use timer insead of while (true) otherwise program might check if condition very frequently using all available resource for that task. And why do you check processArray == null, clearly `processArray = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process));` will only be created ones and would not be updated in the next do while cycle.

Comment: Process.GetProcessesByName does not return null if the process is not running, rather it returns an empty array.

Comment: use the debugger for starters to check the value of processArray have you stepped through the code at least using the debugger..?

Comment: So you have a program. And apart from that program you have two others?

Comment: If your array can contain only 1 element then you shouldn't use array. A simple field would do it as well.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti He doesn't get a choice; the framework method always returns an array

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your biggest problem here is not enough code is in the loop (and its `while(true)`!)

Because you don't reset `programIsRunning` to false (and you really don't even need that variable), or re-get your `Process` array, only the first result will ever run (and really, it only runs if `processArray` is null which it probably isn't, just empty).

You really want something closer to:

```
string process = "file location file name .exe";
do
{
    processArray = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process));
    Console.WriteLine(processArray);
    if (!processArray?.Any() ?? false) 
    {
        Process.Start(process);
    } 
    Thread.Sleep(2000);//IMPORTANT: Sleep or you are doing expensive work in a tight loop!
} while (true);
```

Even that code could be improved *immensely* by putting your loop in a separate thread and having a condition on the while so you can shut it down properly, alternatively, just use a `Timer`. You also don't really need a loop at all since you can attach to the `Exited` event of the process you created in case it shuts down.

Comment: Yeah that worked, but i had to change "!processArray?.any" to "processArray?.any" also what does the "false" mean on the end?

Comment: @Adam That doesn't sound right.... by removing the ! you are saying if the process is already running start it. The false on the end is behind a *null-coalescing* operator and is for the unlikely case that `processArray` is null.

Comment: Okay so i fixed the problem but now ive lost the file due to some OS issues. Now when i use that code if its '!processArray' that file doesnt open at all, if its 'processArray' the file will open no matter what

Comment: @Adam Like I said before, that sounds *very* backwards. Perhaps you should open a new question with the updated details/code?